# The fastest way to make HTTP GET request to a remote URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, httprequest, get-request

I want to get an HTML content of a website. I've tried few things, but most of them are kind of outdated. I'm looking for the most modern and quick way to get response from HTTP GET request.

I'm programming in a chrome extension ecosystem and try to get html of ~120 websites. I know that this is not easy task at all and can't be done within a second or two, but I want to it to make it complete a work within a minute.

I've tried

```
function httpGet(url) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Which takes > 2 minutes.

Thanks.

Comment: "false for synchronous request" — synchronous requests are deprecated for good reason.

Comment: @Quentin Is it related to speed?

Comment: @AlexJ yes it certainly can be. It blocks your entire browser and means you can only do 1 at a time.

Comment: So, I make this `true` and what do I need next? Do I need any `await`, `async` stuff? I've very new to JS stuff.

Comment: @Quentin Synchronous requests are not deprecated, "_synchronous requests __on the main thread__ have been deprecated_"  ...

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, that's what I'm getting in chrome extensions errors. That's one of the reason why am seeking for something modern and faster.

Comment: You can't make faster GET requests. It's beyond your control. What you can make is to throw it back to be processed once the response becomes available. That's called asynchronous processing. Nowadays people mostly use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: You don't return from async calls. Instead of logging, you do the job you need. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: In addition you may also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing